# Missing some of web development utilities in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, razor

I asked question yesterday, which wasn't answered. I gathered some more details and now I am able to ask it more specifically.

Generally, I have two PCs: PC1 and PC2. On both I have VS2017 Community installed. On PC1 everything works just fine.

It's PC2 I have concerns with. First of all, I miss all Razor templates. I can't create ASP.NET project with Razor Views, if I create empty web project, I can't add Razor View (*cshtml* file). To be clear - I can do everything on PC1.

Secondly, on PC1 I have below option, on PC2 I don't:

[image: MissingOption]

I have Web development kit installed in both VS's. I don't know what is wrong.

### Edit

Here's what I get when I navigate to **Web->Web site** in **New project** window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your PC2 is probably on a newer version of VS c17 with the update explained in this blog post:

[Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5 Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/11/visual-studio-2017-version-15-5-preview/)

> Creating ASP.NET Web Applications: We’ve rearranged the ASP.NET project creation menu items a little bit to improve discoverability and increase the likelihood that you’ll choose the right project type for what you’re trying to do. Now, the commands to create a Web Applications or a Web Site are visually next to each other in the File->New Project dialog. This should help the majority of people discover the Create a New Web Application path correctly the first time.

Should just have to go `File>New>Projects...` then there will be a **Web Site** option under **Web**

Comment: What about Razor?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn  If you're referring to ASP.Net Web Pages - aka "Razor web site" (also the type of web site built when using WebMatrix) that's what the above will show you.

Comment: Might actually be an issue with VS windows [This support post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102665/razor-templates-vsmac-2017-vs-vswin-2017-net-standard-2-0) makes it seem that it's a VS issue on windows possibly for the 15.5 version+. If you're able you may want to try taking your VS community version on PC2 back to what your PC1 is on.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing on the path that Justin mentioned? You can try [rerun setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio) if all else fails....

Comment: @MichałTurczyn You are missing one item it seems - the template with Razor3 _scaffolding_ so see if the link above to _rerun setup_ (only to check modify options) works, or check on _Extensions from Microsoft_. Worth noting that the first option, Empty Web site, is a "Razor web site" (just without scaffolding). Hth.